# MySQL: Help to search each word in multiple columns as case insensitive

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that contains: product, cost, comment.

```
Id     product               cost     comment
1      Tires Rex              10      Fast movement good quality
2      Bone Maxx Centri       110     Clean and soft movement
3      Engine damaged         20      Damaged
```

The outcome I want: User can searches multiple words and the query has to find the items with those words as case insensitive.

For example, user searches: **Buy clean tires for cars**

The query output has to show products with **Id** 1 and 2.

Why?

- Because the word **Clean** matches the **comment** in product with **id** 2
- Because the word **tires** matches the **product** with **id** 1

I tried with:

```
SELECT * FROM `inventory` WHERE MATCH (product) AGAINST ('Buy* clean* tires* for* cars*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

But that only works for 1 column and is case-sensitive.

I want it searches in multiples columns as case-insensitive.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: `WHERE MATCH (product)` that means you have search inside one column. However you need to to search inside both `product` & `comment`

Comment: I tried with MATCH (product, comment) but it only searches in the product not in both.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query, it's tested and returns first 2 rows:

```
SELECT * FROM `inventory` WHERE MATCH (product, comment) AGAINST ('Buy* clean* tires* for* cars*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Comment: I tried but It only searches in table product not in both. Another problem is that I want it case-insensitive. Your code is case-sensitive.

Comment: `Another problem is that I want it case-insensitive. Your code is case-sensitive.` what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

I just updated my system using yum update and now is working fine.
Maybe that was the problem.

The problem now is that, is case sensitive. If I search "Clean" it works but if I search "clean" it does not.